# Command line to open the Advanced Security Settings dialogue

Tags: windows, file-permissions

To view the owner of a file or to modify file permissions, you right-click a file, click "Properties", click "Security", and then click "Advanced". This is cumbersome if you do it repeatedly. I would like to add a context menu item to open the same dialogue with one click.

If I knew the command to open the dialogue, I could add something like "command %1" to the Registry.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done programmatically but not directly from the command line.  The system calls require passing specific structures.

Depending on your needs, use the code sample from the Stack Overflow answer below to create an application which accepts a filename and displays the properties dialog.

Creating that application is of course outside the scope of Super User.

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/28246897/91769
>
> You can display the Windows file permissions dialog using
>   `ShellExecuteEx` (using the "properties" verb and the "Security"
>   parameter).
>
> ...
>
> If you were hoping to get the file permissions dialog on its own,
>   rather than as a tab in the general file properties dialog, that is
>   possible using `aclui.dll`, e.g. using the `EditSecurity` function

Comment: It's conceivable that a PowerShell script could do the necessary P/Invoke for the Security tab with `Add-Type` and some C# code, but unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to [open the Advanced Security Settings dialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh285677) without some really gnarly coding. For what it's worth, the normal properties dialog can be called up for a file with `start 'C:\fullPathTo\file.ext' -Verb 'properties'`.

Comment: This only brings the Security property tab page. But it seems there is no way to bring the Advanced dialogue on its own, so I will accept this as the answer. At least now I know that it is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the `icacls` command. for example

```
icacls * .*
```

this will list all files and the security permissions for each.

Comment: That will indeed print out the permissions for all the files, but the question is asking for the Advanced Security Settings GUI to be opened on a given item. Could you please [edit] your answer to accomplish that?

Comment: oh ya, I've read the question wrong. The only way that I know that could be done in a somewhat easy way would be to code it using autoit. But the OP would have to code it. With some help on the autoIT forum that could be doable very easily

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar problem in that one of my folders would give errors synchronising .LNK files in OneDrive. Whenever I had a new .LNK file created, it didn't have sufficient privs. You can right-click each file, and select Security, then edit it, but this is tedious if there are many files. I found the following worked:

> Run CMD as an Administrator

> cd C:\Users\whateverDirectoryYouAreUsing

> icacls *.lnk /grant Interactive:(F)

This grants full Interactive privs, and the files then synch to OneDrive.